# Python - Can't find syntax error in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

Its been a while since I've written code, so I'm trying to get back into it again, but I'm having trouble with some of my code.

I wanted to write a simple program that takes a user's input and checks to see if it is all letters with no spaces, and has a length less than 12. I keep getting an "Invalid syntax" error on line 17 whenever I run the code, pointing to the colon after the if statement that checks if the username is just letters and less than 12 characters. I know that means there's an error on the line before that, but where?

```
#import the os module

import os

#Declare Message

print "Welcome to Userspace - Your One-Stop Destination to Greatness!" + "\n" + "Please enter your username below." \
 + "\n" + "\n" + "Username must be at least 12 characters long, with no spaces or symbols." + "\n" + "\n"

#uinput stands for user's input

uinput = raw_input("Enter a Username: ")

#check_valid checks to see if arguement meets requirements

def check_valid(usrnameinput):
    if (usrnameinput != usrnameinput.isalpha()) or (len(usrnameinput) >= 12):
        os.system('cls')
        print "Invalid Username"
        return False
    else:
        os.system('cls')
        print "Welcome, %s!" % (usrnameinput)
        return True

#Asks for username and checks if its valid

print uinput
check_valid(uinput)

#Checks input to check_valid is correct, and if it is not, then ask for new username input and checks it again

while check_valid(uinput):
    return True
    break
else:
    print uinput
    check_valid(uinput)

print "We hope you enjoy your stay here at Userspace!"
```

UPDATE - I played around with the code a little bit more, and the only thing I changed was the `while` conditional to an `if`:

```
print uinput
check_valid(uinput)

#Checks input to check_valid is correct, and if it is not, then ask for new username input and checks it again

if check_valid(uinput):
    print uinput
    check_valid(uinput)

print "We hope you enjoy your stay here at Userspace!"
```

I ran this code, but got this error instead:

```
  File "Refresher In Python.py", line 39
    return True
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Sorry for being such a noob. Also just joined Stack Overflow today.

Comment: stupid question: which one **is** line 17? Add the full error in verbatim! (that's kind of the obvious thing to do, by the way)

Comment: You have a `return` statement well outside a function. what do you expect `return True` to do in the `while check_valid(uinput):` block? `return` only has meaning *in a function*, and your `while` loop is not in a function.

Comment: Thank you for all the responses! All of this is very helpful. Also, @MarcusMüller, line 17 is `if (usrnameinput != usrnameinput.isalpha()) or (len(usrnameinput) >= 12):`

Comment: @Bearclaw Don't put that in a comment, put it in the actual question. And add the full error.

Comment: The code as posted here has no syntax error other than the use of `return` I mentioned. All of the `check_valid` function parses just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.  I suggest splitting it into two functions, your check_valid() and a general main() function.

```
def check_valid(usrnameinput):

    if (not usrnameinput.isalpha()) or (len(usrnameinput) >= 12):
        print("Invalid name")
        return False
    else:
        print("Welcome!")
        return True

def main():

    uinput = raw_input("Enter a Username: ")
    while not check_valid(uinput): #Repeatedly asks user for name.
        uinput = raw_input("Enter a Username: ")

main()
```

Comment: I get this error when I try running it with your suggestion: `File "Refresher In Python.py", line 39
    return True
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` which is a blank line.

Comment: I believe you have some other code that's interfering with this.  If you ran exactly what I posted, that shouldn't be happening.  There is no 'return' outside function in the code I just posted.

Comment: I think something is wrong with my IDE wouldn't run the code correctly until I restarted the program. It worked, thank you.

Comment: If my code helped, I would appreciate if you accepted the answer.  Otherwise, have a great one :)